# Writing a red black tree program insertion where we can't use recursion

Tags: java, recursion, iteration

This program works recursively but, I'm trying to do it not recursively while not having to change the method parameters.  Thanks anything will help!

```
private Node insertTree(Node root, Node node) { //root and node is current vs. next
        
        if (root == null) { 
            return node;  
        
        }
        
        if(node.getCurrentNum() < root.getCurrentNum()) { //Means it is a left child
            root.setLeftChild(insertTree(root.getLeftChild(), node)); //RECURSIVE MUST FIX
            root.getLeftChild().setParent(root); 
        }
        
        else if(node.getCurrentNum() >root.getCurrentNum()) { //Means it is a right child
            root.setRightChild(insertTree(root.getRightChild(), node)); //RECURSIVE MUST FIX
            root.getRightChild().setParent(root); 
        }
        
        return root;
        
    }
        
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your attempt?

Comment: Andreas changed it to a private void, in my case I have classes/constructors built on returning the root from the insertTree method.  So, I changed it back to the original method parameters and used my root (used as the numbers from the text file)and returned the root after the loops were complete.  I also got rid of the empty returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only follow either `leftChild` **or** `rightChild`, never both on the same `Node`, you don't need backtracking, so can easily do this with a loop.

```java
private void insertTree(Node newNode) {
    if (this.root == null) {
        this.root = newNode;
        newNode.setParent(null);
        return;
    }
    Node parent = this.root;
    while (newNode.getCurrentNum() != parent.getCurrentNum()) {
        if (newNode.getCurrentNum() < parent.getCurrentNum()) {
            if (parent.getLeftChild() == null) {
                parent.setLeftChild(newNode);
                newNode.setParent(parent);
                return;
            }
            parent = parent.getLeftChild();
        } else if (newNode.getCurrentNum() > parent.getCurrentNum()) {
            if (parent.getRightChild() == null) {
                parent.setRightChild(newNode);
                newNode.setParent(parent);
                return;
            }
            parent = parent.getRightChild();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With some minor changes this worked.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the end this is what I got thanks to Andreas.

```
private Node insertTree(Node root, Node newNode) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = newNode;
            newNode.setParent(null);
        }

        Node parent = root;

        while (newNode.getCurrentNum() != parent.getCurrentNum()) {
            if (newNode.getCurrentNum() < parent.getCurrentNum()) {
                if (parent.getLeftChild() == null) {
                    parent.setLeftChild(newNode);
                    newNode.setParent(parent);
                }
                parent = parent.getLeftChild();
            } else if (newNode.getCurrentNum() > parent.getCurrentNum()) {
                if (parent.getRightChild() == null) {
                    parent.setRightChild(newNode);
                    newNode.setParent(parent);

                }
                parent = parent.getRightChild();
            }
        }

        return root;
    }
```